# Can we use Condition with axes in XPATH?

Tags: selenium, xpath, conditional-statements, axes

Can we use Condition with axes in XPATH?

Trying to check both parent and child in XPath. Example:

```
//span[text()='Accounts']/parent::a OR child::div
```

I know this is wrong. But is there any way to check the condition?

I know the situation looks vague. But I am trying to find a logic where I can use both parent and child axes to create an XPath.
The main motive is to inspect an element from UI and create XPath using axes. and automate the process.

When I am trying the above XPath, it throws some error.

Comment: Please edit your post with a representative xml and your exact desired output.

Comment: Your XPath is syntactically valid but doesn't make much sense. I can't correct it for you without knowing what you intended it to mean, which I can't guess. Inferring requirements from incorrect code is a mug's game.

Comment: Agree with the previous commenters: please post a minimal example of your input document and expected output. You probably do not need to use both of those axes at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you use | instead of OR

```
//span[text()='Accounts']/(parent::a|child::div)
```